# iOS 14 Background picture not updating until app reloads

Tags: swift, ios14

Can anyone tell me why the following code works perfectly when it runs the first time, or when the app reloads? It does not however change the VC background image, although I can see it step through the code. The image does load correctly when the app is swiped away and reloaded.

I am stumped. Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Blessings,
--Mark

```
if CacheManager.getIsUserBackGround() {
                
                //get a refrerence to the the documents for the app
                let fileManager = FileManager.default
                //get the path from Constants
                let imagePath = Constants.getImage()
                
                
                //check if not nil, and if not set the background pict
                if imagePath != "" {
                    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: imagePath!) {
                        
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
                            backgroundImage.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)!
                            backgroundImage.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
                            self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)
                        }
                        
                    }else{
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            print("error")
    //                        Alerts.showAlert(title: "Attention", message: "A user selected image from the Photos Library has not been saved. \n \n Tap the Gear icon on the 'Lists' screen and select the 'Set background from Photos' option to save an image.", vc: self)
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I make things WAY harder than they need to be!

I discovered that I was adding a view (and the memory overhead) each time I changed the image and when the app reset, it just used the last image saved.

The simple solution was to ignore the background view and add a UIImageView and change the image to that! Live and learn!